# Zipalign - Command not found - MAC terminal

Tags: android, macos, terminal, command

When I try to run Zipalign on an apk I get the error `"Command not found"`

I am not that familiar with using terminal commands on the MAC but I have navigated to the SDK/Tools folder and run the following command:

```
zipalign -v 4 Project1.apk Project1-aligned.apk
```

I get Command not found

I have tried placing the apks in the Tools folder and same result.

Can someone help me to understand where the apks should be located and where I should run zipalign from?

Thanks, I am very frustrated about this as it seems so simple.

Answer (score 87):

You can find correct path with this command:

```
find ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools -name "zipalign"
```

Comment: You should receive a honor medal for this comment. You saved my life. Thanks, thanks and thanks again!!!

Comment: Yes, thank you that works. On my Mac the command yields:
/Users/nicolasscozzaro/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.2/zipalign

Comment: Medal of Honor for you!

Answer (score 78):

Perhaps the current directory is not in your path?

Try adding "./" before your command so

```
./zipalign -v 4 Project1.apk Project1-aligned.apk
```

Comment: I will try, thanks.  I will also include the full path to the apk.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer, @Bill please mark this as correct answer if this solved your problem!! it always encourage people who answer questions.

Comment: Worked as advertised for me.

Comment: Can a moderator marks this as the answer?

Answer (score 52):

You will find the zipalign tool at `/path/to/sdk/build-tools/<build-tools-version>/zipalign` **NOT** in the tools folder anymore.

Answer (score 37):

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/xxxx/zipalign
```

Drag this to terminal or save this in your path.
xxxx -> Version

Answer (score 27):

Zipalign is a command that located at `$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/{android-version}/`.

Hope it helped.

Comment: ANDROID, not ADROD. But, thanks for your answer, it helped me.

Answer (score 21):

A simple one-liner:

- This adds a line in your profile, to add the directory which contains the zipalign executable to your path
- Then reloads the profile

`echo "export PATH=\$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/" >> ~/.bash_profile && . ~/.bash_profile`

Make sure to replace **23.0.1** with your installed version

```
$ ls -l ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  23.0.1 <---
```

Now you should be able to use zipalign regardless of your current working dir

`$ zipalign`

Comment: This is much more helpful.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  23.0.1 <--- this line didn't give me the real version number, but after I fix it, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: this is the real answer since by adding dir to PATH other tools in that dir like aapt can also be found

Answer (score 15):

on the mac with the zsh console, my solution was

command 1)

```
find ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools -name "zipalign"
----------------------------------------------------------
/Users/macOs/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/zipalign
/Users/macOs/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/zipalign
/Users/macOs/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/zipalign
/Users/macOs/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/zipalign
```

command 2)

```
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/" >> ~/.bash_profile && . ~/.bash_profile
```

command 3)

```
ls -l ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/
```

command 4)

```
zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk nameApp.apk
```

Answer (score 10):

2hours resume for newbies (like me) :

If you type this command :

```
zipalign -v 4 platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk app-release.apk
```

Witch gives you :

```
command not found: zipalign
```

It's maybe that the path is somewhere wrong.
If you have this :

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

It confirms that its not really as it should be. So, to execute zipalign and finally publish your app, you have to go in the correct repository and execute commande.

**1. Go to the correct repo to execute command :**

The path is cd /Users/xxxyour_user_namexxx/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/xxxxx/

```
cd /Users/greg/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3
```

**2. Execute your zipalign command, don't forget to precise the path of apk file :**

Obviously, chance "greg" and "myapp" with your user name & app name.

```
./zipalign -v 4 /Users/greg/Desktop/AppLocal/myapp/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk /Users/greg/Desktop/AppLocal/myapp/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

Search it and reference it... I have it here and reference it like this:

/Users/lioncio/Desktop/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/zipalign bla bla bla (all the options of the command!)

And worked

Answer (score 8):

**Relax**! , Just Use **`Locate`** Command  in Terminal **WHEREVER** it is , it will come out

```
tom-MacBook-Air:kavform_app tom$ locate zipalign

/Users/tom/Software/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/24.0.1/zipalign

/Users/tom/Software/android-sdk-macosx/docs/tools/help/zipalign.html
```

In my case it was burried over here

```
/Users/tom/Software/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/24.0.1/zipalign -v 4 /Users/tom/kavwork/kavform/kavform_app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk BrideToBe.apk
```

Comment: I think this works just wanted to let you know you get this the first time it is run and have to wait a bit: "Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear."

Answer (score 5):

add it to the path

on terminal

find path for zip align

```
find ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools -name "zipalign"
```

path: **/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/zipalign**

enter the path found in there

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

> now on new terminal you can see zipalign reco

Comment: The path you add to /etc/paths should be without `/zipalign`

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Mac

This error basically means that the terminal wasn't able to find the zipalign file.
So you can either type in the full path for your zipalign file with the command (located in your Android build-tools folder)

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/zipalign -v 4 android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk helloWorld.apk;
```

If you do not know the location of the zipalign file, then just use this command

```
find ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools -name "zipalign"
```

Comment: is there a way to store the url that find returns? I'd like it to be dynamic

Comment: Not any that I know of. 
Although, you can of course create a batch file that fetches the path, and then runs the command.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on Windows, change the command prompt to point to the folder containing the zipalign.exe and then run the command. Also, I have found that you are not using the complete command:

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] 4 Input.apk Output.apk
```

Answer (score 2):

`cd android-sdk/build-tools/22.0.0/` - change directory to android sdk folder, build tools and choose version (I used 22.0.0).

Then at the prompt type:

```
./zipalign -v 4 /MyApp/android-x86-release-signed.apk ~/MyApp/android-x86-release-signedandzipped.apk
```

That worked for me.  I tried the other solutions above with no success. I just had to run the command withn the proper folder, but that wasn't explained clearly in other resources I checked.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the path of the zip align and include that with the command

**`/Users/ignatiusandrew/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/zipalign 4 android-release-unsigned.apk igi.apk`**

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you do not want to add a specific build tools folder to the path, in case it changes in the future, you can use the first result of `find` command:

`$(find ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools -name "zipalign"  | head -n 1) <your-zipalign-parameters>`

It might be especially useful in a CI pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked perfectly, I copied the zipalign file from the android path to the folder where I wanted to run command and then typed ./zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.sdk nameofapp.apk

Note: It was on Mac

Answer (score 0):

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\\build-tools\\25.0.2\\zipalign -v 4 .\\platforms\\android\\build\\outputs\\apk\\input.apk .\\path\\ output.apk
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider expanding this answer to explain why you believe the users are unable to make this command work and how executing it like this fixes the issue. Also it may be worth adding some text detailing how a user could add this to their PATH so that they can execute it like OP tried in the question. Those 2 edits would make this answer to a very old question much more useful for people looking for a good answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, 
if your android home is set, then you can just 
    `cd $ANDROID_HOME`
and 
  `open .` (This should be  - /Users/username/Library/Android/, you can just cd to that path as well)

Next, navigate to "sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/" (version 25.0.3 in this case, yours may be a different version).

At your terminal (apk prompt), drag zipalign to the terminal and 
`...../zipalign -v -p 4 my-app-unsigned.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk`.
Should work fine.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded zipalign-file from github

```
zipalign exec copy and paste in your Project1-aligned.apk directory
./zipalign -v 4 Project1.apk Project1-aligned.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case 
I follow below answer

1. Change directory

   /path/to/sdk/build-tools//zipalign
2. Type

   ./zipalign instead zipalign

In short ./zipalign is solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Jenkins**

For Jenkins users using MacOS to build and sign mobile apps who are experiencing this error, the solution could be this:

At the stage where the signature is made:

```
withEnv(['PATH=/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3', 
'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk', 
'JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home'])
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Windows with git bash/command promt

zipalign.exe needed to be configured in environment variables.

so include sdk folder 'build-tool' with android version folder you are using to build.

```
e.g. E:\android-sdk\build-tools\22.0.1
```

it should contain 'zipalign.exe'. now you can user

```
zipalign -v 4 Project1.apk Project1-aligned.apk
```

from any location using command line tools.

thumb up for me so i can help more developers.