# zipalign: command not found - Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

I am trying to zipalign an "input.apk" file on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system using the command line as I do not have access to the source code just yet. If I'm not mistaken I should  be able to do this with the following command

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] 4 intput.apk output.apk
```

but I am getting the following output

```
zipalign: command not found
```

I have made sure that the zipalign file is in my ...sdk/tools directory which I had to copy over from my ...build-tools/android-4.4W folder because it was originally missing. When I input this line as suggested in another question

```
./zipalign [-f] [-v] 4 intput.apk output.apk
```

I get the following output

```
Zip alignment utility
Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

Usage: zipalign [-f] [-v] <align> infile.zip outfile.zip
       zipalign -c [-v] <align> infile.zip

   <align>: alignment in bytes, e.g. '4' provides 32-bit alignment
   -c: check alignment only (does not modify file)
   -f: overwrite existing outfile.zip
   -v: verbose output
```

Does this mean that I need a .zip file instead of my .apk to zipalign?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327266/zipalign-command-not-found-mac-terminal

Comment: yea the answers in that post did not work for me, I think I'm still doing something wrong

Comment: Try to run this command : ./zipalign -v 4 intput.apk output.apk

Comment: @Haresh Worked! thanks you. I guess the -f and -c commands need an output file to begin with or something

Comment: can you please approve ans so it may help others?

Comment: @himahimahima, do not edit answers into questions. Questions should *only* be marked solved by clicking the checkbox next to the answer the OP selects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When a usage message contains an argument in brackets, the brackets mean that that argument is optional and can be left out of the final command; the brackets are not themselves part of the command syntax.

In your case, correct usage might look like:

```
./zipalign -v 4 intput.apk output.apk
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer. It took me almost 1 hour to find the issue .. You made my day Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help you @Jose

Comment: launching this command on a 64 bit machine can also not be enough giving "zipalign: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" as it happened to me... in this case I solved with liauau's answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336697/zipalign-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libc-so-cannot-open-shared-ob

Answer (score 11):

In terminal,

```
cd /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/21.1.2

sudo ln -sf zipalign /usr/bin/

zipalign -v 4 platforms/android/ant-build/MainActivity-release-unsigned.apk platforms/android/ant-build/YOUR_APP.apk
```

Comment: jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~/workspace/PP_androidBuild/PatientPortal$ zipalign -v 4  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/PatientPortal/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Zip alignment utility
Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
Usage: zipalign [-f] [-p] [-v] [-z] <align> infile.zip outfile.zip
       zipalign -c [-v] <align> infile.zip
  <align>: alignment in bytes, e.g. '4' provides 32-bit alignment
  -c: check alignment only (does not modify file)
  -f: overwrite existing outfile.zip

  -v: verbose output

Answer (score 3):

1. Open terminal (CTRL + t)
2. cd YOUR_PATH/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/XX.X.X
3. sudo cp zipalign /usr/bin/
4. Open the folder where is located your apk in the terminal.
5. Execute zipalign -v 4 YOUR_APK.apk YOUR_APK.apk

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same issue. This is how i solved it, all you need is here.** 

*1. Get zipalign path by getting sdk path on android studio. which is* `/Users/s****/Library/Android/sdk` for me. 
*2. Paste the path on your terminal and cd to "build-tools/28.0.3/zipalign" now command will be*
`/Users/s****/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/zipalign`
3. *zip the apk on the same command line by adding `-v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk my.apk`to the command, now command will be* 
`/Users/s****/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk my.apk`

 4. ***Done.***