# zipalign: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: android, apk, ubuntu-14.04, libc++, aptitude

I am trying to build android app. When I run the zip align tool to optimize the APK, I get this error message:

```
zipalign: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install libc++

```
sudo aptitude install libc++
```

it says: Couldn't find package "libc+".

Snapshot of my terminal

[image: Snapshot of my terminal]

Answer (score 7):

If your system is 64-bits, there should be a folder lib64 on the path of

```
 [android-path]/build-tools/[version]/
```

The files in lib64 are

```
[ec2-user 25.0.2]$ ll lib64/
total 51628
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 30712616 Dec 23 07:22 libLLVM.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user   482522 Dec 23 07:22 libbcc.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user   433914 Dec 23 07:22 libbcinfo.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user  1211614 Dec 23 07:22 libc++.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 20019608 Dec 23 07:22 libclang.so
```

Just copy the folder lib64 and zipalign program together to the destination path, and you can run the zipalign correctly. 
It worked for me. I guess the zipalign has a dependency on the files in lib64 folder.

Comment: This answer helped with the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problems and google it. You can try the following suggestions:

1. If you are in 64-bit environment, try: sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev.
2. Update the latest android sdk tools and do not move the zipalign binary to any other folder. It solve my problem.

Comment: I had tried to install these dependencies. It installed  without any problem. but, the zipalign error is not solved. is there any other dependency that I need to install? Sorry for very late reply.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and it was probably because I moved the `zipalign` binary from `<android-path>/build-tools/23.0.3` to `<android-path>/tools`.

The solution is to add the `build-tools/23.0.3` dir to your path:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:<android-path>/build-tools/23.0.3
```