# How to get zipalign for mac?

Tags: macos, zipalign

I already have a release unsigned version apk and I am trying to sign it on my mac. On the last step it suggests to zipalign the signed apk but mac doesn't have zipalign.

I did 'brew search ' still can't find it. I searched online and can't find standalone zipalign script. I even downloaded around 90M Android sdk tool from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other  but still found no zipalign inside.

So my question is, given you an "apk" file to sign on mac, how to get through the last "zipalign" step?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zipalign - Command not found - MAC terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327266/zipalign-command-not-found-mac-terminal)

Comment: Are you indicating in order to use 'zipalign' I have to download 250M android studio and install it on mac? Cause all those posts mentioned some sort of android sdk install path.

Comment: I think so yes but no guarantee

Comment: if you have the SDK installed you should be able to do "android zipalign -v file.apk dest.apk" on your command line

Answer (score 34):

Thanks the info from RC.

I finally got through this. I did in following steps:

1. Download 250M+ android studio ide dmg from official site. Drag it into Application folder
2. Open it, and it automatically downloads a lot of additional stuff
3. I even created a empty new project.

Then in certain step(I am not sure which step) it created zipalign here:

~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/zipalign

If you only need "zipalign", you don't need to redo those steps, which takes time and disk space. I extracted it into the github(Can't believe no one has extracted it -_- ):

https://github.com/catccaatt/zipalign

Comment: Mac users: If you get an error similar to: 
unable to execute ./zipalign: Bad CPU type in executable, 
you may need the 64bit version of ZipAlign. Available here: https://github.com/spanishsnapper/zipalign (extracted from Studio 29.0.2)

Answer (score 15):

From your Mac terminal:

Add adb to command line path:

```
echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Add build tools to command line path:

```
echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/28.0.2' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Refresh command line with:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you can run it with:

```
zipalign -v -p 4 my-app-unsigned.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

Comment: make sure build-tools/version matches your installed version mine was 28.0.3.

Comment: You can use 
find ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools -name "zipalign" to find the zipalign path in your system