# Zipalign Problems Building Android App on MAC

Tags: android, bash, macos, build, ionic2

I can't execute zipalign command on my MAC.
I'm preparing an app to be published on Play Store but I'm stuck at this point.

I've searched for zipalign throw all my folders but I can't find it, so I downloaded it following this topic: [How to get zipalign for mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998688/how-to-get-zipalign-for-mac)

When I run the following command I get "Permission denied" message instead.

```
./zipalign MyApk.apk MyApkAligned.apk
Permission denied
```

If I simply run the following command I get "-bash zipalign: command not found".

```
zipalign MyApk.apk MyApkAligned.apk
-bash zipalign: command not found
```

Could you give me any support on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

[Zipalign - Command not found - MAC terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327266/zipalign-command-not-found-mac-terminal)

This topic solved my problems. Using "find" bash command line did the trick, I just copy the right path and then it worked.